# Open an angular template reference in a new browser window

Tags: html, angular, angular-components

So here is the explanation of the problem I am facing. It might look very similar other already asked questions, but none of them answered my problem.

I want to open an angular template reference in a new browser window (with all the styles) and use that window to print the contents using system print dialog.

By template reference I mean a whole component or may be just a fraction of template of given component.

Please note that I do not want to do it by below methods:

1. Opening a new route in a new browser window. (Why? this will cause all other things like common toolbar or help open up with the component. Also a new route will be required which is undesired.)
2. Opening the content in a closable modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, This is how I did it using `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `Injector`. Just inject these two dependencies in your component which wants to open other component (`ReportComponent` in this case) in new browser window.

The constructor looks something like this in snippet below.

```
  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {}
```

.
.
.

This method opens up the component in new browser window.

```
public openPrintableReport(): void {

// resolve and instantiate the component which you want to open in new window. 
const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ReportComponent);
let component = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

// define external window
this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=1000,height=1000,left=150,top=200');

// copy all the styles to external window.
document.querySelectorAll('style').forEach(htmlElement => {
  this.externalWindow.document.head.appendChild(htmlElement.cloneNode(true));
});

this.externalWindow.document.title = 'Printer Friendly Report';

// attach the component to external window
this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(component.location.nativeElement);
}
```